# Word to describe that only one side of the party is talking?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentences:

> Susan didn't enjoy the date, because it was too __.
>
> Mary's marriage has become __. She's the only one speaking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"One-sided" is common usage and would work in both of your examples; however, its usage is broader than just about conversations -- though it is often used to modify 'conversation' (see many results for 'one-sided conversation' google search, or http://www.basicinstructions.net/basic-instructions/2009/4/29/how-to-end-a-one-sided-conversation.html).

If you wanted to avoid usage of one-sided, your options for a one-word solution might be limited or awkward. There are some idioms for what you describe, such as:

- She *dominated* the conversation
- He *monopolized* the conversation

You may also consider use of the word "monologue," which has the usage "a prolonged talk or discourse by a single speaker, especially one dominating or monopolizing a conversation" (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monologue).

Answer (score 5):

One could say that the conversation was *lopsided*:

**Lopsided**:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 With one side lower or smaller than the other.
>
> ‘a lopsided grin’
>
> 1.1 Disproportionately weighted in favor of one side over another.
>
> ‘a lopsided competition’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lopsided

If it suits, you might also explore concepts such as unbalanced or uneven.

Answer (score 1):

**Unilateral** is another possibilty for your second example:

> adjective
>
> (of an action or decision) performed by or affecting only one person,
>   group, or country involved in a situation, without the agreement of
>   another or the others.

(from https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unilateral)

It is simply a highfalutin way to say *onesided*, which was already given.

Answer (score -1):

monologue:

A monologue is a speech delivered by one person, or a long one-sided conversation that makes you want to pull your hair out from boredom. The Greek root word monologos translates to “speaking alone,” and that's a monologue: one person doing all the talking.

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange. If you have any questions, please consult the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). As it currently stands, your post is severely lacking in any form of citation. Please provide sources to back up your answer, and elaborate on why you think this word adequately answers the original question.